# Static Routing in Express.js returning 404 Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to create routing for different pages of my website, using express.js. 
When going to 127.0.0.1:8080, it loads the index.html page fine, however, when I go to 127.0.0.1:8080/questionaire, it comes back with a 404 error and doesn't load questionaire.html. I thought that using the line:

```
app.use(express.static('client', { extensions: ['html'] }));
```

meant that this would be possible, however, it doesn't work. If there is a better way to do this then fixing the solution, inform me please.

**Directory**

```
client
-- index.html
-- index.js
-- questionaire.html
-- questionaire.js
svr.js
viewapi.js
```

**svr.js**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const view_api = require('./viewapi');

app.use(express.static('client', { extensions: ['html'] }));

const api = require('./api');

app.use('/view', view_api); // routing to api which will get data in form of JSON

app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your setup and loading questionare.html worked fine for me. Did you receive any other errors from the Express server when you tried to load the page? I'm asking because I'm not sure what the contents are inside `viewapi.js` so when I tested it, I didn't have that file.

However, to answer this:

> If there is a better way to do this then fixing the solution, inform me please.

it's good practice to separate the assets that you serve (html, css, js, images, etc.). For example, you could create sub-folders inside your `client` folder and put your static files in the appropriate folder.

You can also find examples and better documentation here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I just deleted and readded the app.use(express.static('client', { extensions: ['html'] })); line and somehow it worked. Will look into seperating the files.